# Testing a composed Reactjs component with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I followed the React documentation's advice to create a specialised component through composition:

```
export default class AlertPanel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
                textRows = <div>{this.props.text}</div>;
            }

            return (
               <Alert bsStyle={this.props.style} onDismiss={this.props.onDismiss}>
                    {textRows} 
               </Alert>
            );
    }
```

... and ...

```
import React from 'react';
import AlertPanel from './AlertPanel';

export default class SpecialAlertPanel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <AlertPanel text="special" />
        ) ;
    }
}
```

`AlertPanel` has a passing test:

```
it( 'should render AlertPanel to a div', function() { 
    const wrapper = shallow( <AlertPanel /> );
    expect( wrapper.type() ).to.eql( 'div' );
});
```

I thought an equivalent test would work for `SpecialAlertPanel`:

```
it( 'should render SpecialAlertPanel to a div', function() {
    const wrapper = shallow( <SpecialAlertPanel /> );
    expect( wrapper.type() ).to.eql( 'div' );
});
```

But this test fails:

```
expected [Function: AlertPanel] to deeply equal 'div'
```

Is my test or my code at fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do shallow rendering SpecialAlertPanel is rendered down to AlertPanel but not "deeper" (http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/shallow.html)

Most likely you need something like

```
it( 'should render SpecialAlertPanel to a div', function() {
  const wrapper = shallow( <SpecialAlertPanel /> );
  expect(wrapper.find(AlertPanel).shallow().type()).to.eql('div');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/type.md:

> If it's a composite component, this will be the component constructor.

So `SpecialAlertPanel`'s wrapper type is `AlertPanel`.

If you want the test to pass, wrap `AlertPanel` in a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different to @Igor and @RemLampa's correct answers. Another view on it is - What should you be testing `SpecialAlertPanel` for?

With the examples you have shown, you have an `AlertPanel` component and it is tested.

`SpecialAlertPanel`'s only function is to render `AlertPanel`.

Testing `SpecialAlertPanel` for a `<div>` is duplicating `AlertPanel`'s test.

Really all you need to be testing is if `SpecialAlertPanel` is rendering an `AlertPanel`. If `AlertPanel` passes it's tests and `SpecialAlertPanel` passes the test to check for an `AlertPanel`, then you already know that it is rendering a `<div>`, without needing to explicitly test for it.

(Of course you would need to add tests to `SpecialAlertPanel` if you add extra functionality in the future)

Comment: Yes, this is a simple example upon which I want to build extra tests on `SpecialAlertPanel` as I add functionality to it.